# Peer to peer communication over NAT

Tags: networking, network-programming

I have two peer devices which are behind NAT. But the problem comes while establishing communication between them, as there are four different types of NAT and each observing a different behaviour. What can be the possible solution in this scenario? 
Also I have a STUN server which is used to relay the IP addresses and port number of the peer device.

Comment: Have you seen how WebRTC uses STUN, TURN, and ICE for NAT traversal?

Answer (score 0):

Without access to some interface with which you can configure the NAT'ing on the gateways, you can't establish a connection. Simple as that. NAT is designed to forward communication packets to the (hidden) host behind the NAT that is a) configured to get packets for that specific port or b) based on tracked connections.

Typically, this problem is overcome in SOHO routers by employing UPnP, which allows to set up port forwardings "on the fly". Knowing that this basically is the same as shutting down the firewall and exposing a PC, you won't get that in institutional networks. Your only choice then is to use a third party as kind of a broker/proxy or to use VPN technologies to "bridge" these networks (or to bring one party into the other party's network, to be more specific).

Comment: Actually the question i asked is that i have two dynamic mobile peer devices anywhere. And they have an access to a stun server. Now stun server has ip and port number which would be specific to connection between server and peer. Now when i am trying to establish new connection to another, NAT would have changed the port number for this new connection. Hence connection wont be establish. I want a solution that can be applied for general case.

Comment: There's no general case, sorry.

Comment: And STUN only gives you your own public IP address. It doesn't help open a gate through your NAT.

Comment: The point is that most administrators actively need to make opening a connection from the outside (internet) to the inside (corporate LAN) impossible. That's a standard security objective. You will need to have all your potential clients connect to a central, non-NATed server if you want a "general" solution. P2P file sharing networks have had the same problem for two decades, and the solution they've come up with is simply "letting those who can configure port forwardings do that, and let the others only connect to these". This is no general solution. There can be **no** general case.

Comment: This would be a problem in corporate LAN. But in home network, we can initiate a torrent download. How can torrent download work in this conditions?

Comment: Wrote that three times: Home routers often have UPnP that allows configuring port forwarding. Very convenient, horrendously insecure. Not generally available.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will try to implement using uPnP it works in our scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This paper has been very useful to me in order to learn about hole punching: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix05/tech/general/full_papers/ford/ford.pdf

As last option, when you cannot do hole punching, what everybody does is the typical implementation through a server. Peer A and Peer B have a connection through a server that they can poll all the time.

Comment: Have gone through this paper, but in this they have assumed NAT to be well behaved. But for general case the NAT would be changing the outgoing port for each connection and hence there comes the problem. Once the central server has the info for IP and port but the second time a peer tries to establish a connection port number would have changed and there is no use of the data stored in the central server.

Comment: @RahulSingh, you have to repeat the process for every connection. this is the way you solve this problem.